# Numpy: Dotproduct of all vectors in a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, dot-product

Say I have a list of 800 vectors and every vector consists of 1440 scalars.

```
List = [(1, 2, 3, ... , 1440),
        (1, 2, 3, ... , 1440),
        (1, 2, 3, ... , 1440),
        ...]
```

How can I calculate the dot product of every vector to each other vector in the fastest way with python and numpy?

Comment: What is your attempt?

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.multi_dot.html ?

Comment: what is the expected shape for your desired result? Is it a symmetric matrix where `x_ij` is the dot product of `a_i` with `a_j`?

Comment: the vectors describe images. I want to compare them by getting the dot product of the vectors. Then I want to arrange them on a canvas

Comment: is the answer I provided what you were looking for?

Comment: i am still trying to understand it. I will answer you tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

If you want the symmetric matrix where `x_ij` is the dot product of `a_i` with `a_j`, then:

```py
a = np.array(List)
x = a @ a.T
```

Comment: what does the @ mean stand for?

Comment: `@` [stands for matrix multiplication](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html). See also [PEP-465](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.triu_indices` or `np.tril_indices` to avoid computing the second half of the matrix. This won't affect the complexity of the computation, but may save some time for a sufficient number of long vectors:

```
a = np.array(x)
n = a.shape[0]
r, c = np.triu_indices(n)
result = np.empty((n, n))
result[r, c] = result[c, r] = np.sum(a[r] * a[c], axis=1)
```